# How do i use params in AWSAthenaOperator?

Tags: airflow, amazon-athena

in a dag I have something like:

```
op = AWSAthenaOperator(

   params={"myparm": myvalue}
   query=query.sql
```

where query.sql is:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(
"datefield",
"anotherfield"
)
SELECT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        {{params.myparm}}
```

When i try to run this i get `mismatched input '{'`. I try and put double quotes round it but then Athena seems to think it is a DB field that does not exist. If I put single quotes I get the literal value `{{params.myparm}` stored in the DB.
Is there any way of doiing this? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Using the airflow cli you can [test render task](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#render) and check the output.

Here is a working example of params in sql files, that we us daily.

```
add_partition = AthenaOperator(
    task_id="add_partition",
    query=ADD_PARTITION_SQL,
    database=ATHENA_DB,
    params={"external_table_name": "table_name", "company": COMPANY},
)

ALTER TABLE `{{ params.external_table_name }}`
    ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (dt = '{{ ds }}', company = '{{ params.company }}');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank ou this is helpful. I wonder if my problem is something i forgot to mention. i have to use Airflow 2.3.0. Maybe it works in later versions.

Comment: What version of the Amazon providers do you have installed?